# Confidence interval for sentiment analysis: proportion_confint vs t.interval difference?

Tags: python, confidence-interval, scipy

I have been working with sentiment analysis for a paper and my advisor wants me to have a confidence interval for everything.

Here is my data:

```
                                  type       label     count
0                         aide memoire      negative    102
1                         aide memoire      positive    128
2                             briefing      negative    176
3                             briefing      positive    141
4                                draft      negative    160
5                                draft      positive    144
```

I want to find two things:

**1.  Find the percentage of negative and positive sentiments for each type of document. Then, find the confidence interval of this percentage.**

What I have done:

Found the percentages:

```
                                  type       label     count   sent_frequency  
0                         aide memoire      negative    102        0.443478   
1                         aide memoire      positive    128        0.556522   
2                             briefing      negative    176        0.555205   
3                             briefing      positive    141        0.444795   
4                                draft      negative    160        0.526316   
5                                draft      positive    144        0.473684
```

For the **confidence interval**, I did the following using `proportion_confint`:

```
confidence_intervals = []
for type in data['type'].unique():
    for sentiment in data['label'].unique():
            lower_ci, upper_ci = proportion_confint(data.loc[(data['type']==type) & (data['label']== sentiment), 'count'].iloc[-1], data.loc[data['type']==type, 'count'].sum(), alpha=0.05, method='wilson')
```

Giving me this:

```
                              type            label   lower_ci  upper_ci
0                         aide memoire      negative  0.380726  0.508088
1                         aide memoire      positive  0.491912  0.619274
2                             briefing      negative  0.500164  0.608924
3                             briefing      positive  0.391076  0.499836
4                                draft      negative  0.470210  0.581765
5                                draft      positive  0.418235  0.529790
```

**2. Find the delta values (positive percentage - negative percentage) for a specific type of document over time (there is a column `datetime`). Then, find the confidence interval of this difference.**

What I have done:

I filtered the data only to a selected type of document, like this:

```
     datetime       label     count    sent_frequency
0  1956-07-31      positive      4        1.000000
1  1957-07-31      negative     90        0.422535
2  1957-07-31      positive    123        0.577465
3  1958-07-31      negative    100        0.546448
4  1958-07-31      positive     83        0.453552
5  1960-07-31      negative     94        0.362934
6  1960-07-31      positive    165        0.637066
7  1961-07-31      negative     87        0.345238
8  1961-07-31      positive    165        0.654762
9  1962-07-31      negative    202        0.411405
10 1962-07-31      positive    289        0.588595
11 1963-07-31      negative    117        0.455253
12 1963-07-31      positive    140        0.544747
13 1965-07-31      negative    143        0.496528
14 1965-07-31      positive    145        0.503472
15 1956-07-31      negative      0        0.000000
```

Then I found the delta values (positive percentage - negative percentage) for each `datetime` and used the `t.interval` function to create the ci.

```
freq_pos = data.loc[data['label'] == 'positive', 'sent_frequency'].values
freq_neg = data.loc[data['label'] == 'negative', 'sent_frequency'].values
difference_arg = data.loc[data['label'] == 'positive', 'sent_frequency'].values - data.loc[data['label'] == 'negative', 'sent_frequency'].values
difference_arg = pd.DataFrame(difference_arg)
difference_arg.columns = ['difference']
    
# Calculate the standard error and confidence interval for the difference
count_total = count_sent_arg.groupby('type').sum()['count']
se = ((freq_pos * (1 - freq_pos)) / count_total) + ((freq_neg * (1 - freq_neg)) / count_total)
se = se.apply(lambda x: x**0.5)
difference['ci_lower'], difference['ci_upper'] = difference.apply(lambda x: t.interval(alpha=0.95, df=len(data['datetime'].unique())-1, loc=x['difference'], scale=se[x.name]), axis=1).apply(pd.Series).values.T
```

**Question**

I have done some search, and I found the `proportion_confint` and `t.interval` are different methods. Does it make sense to use two different ways of finding the confidence interval for these two scenarios? Is the application of these methods correct?

I will have a meeting with my advisor soon and I want to be able to explain the ci methods I used and be sure that they are correctly applied.

t.interval: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.t.html

proportion_confint: https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/generated/statsmodels.stats.proportion.proportion_confint.html